# Using Iterm2 password manager on a mac always fails by saying "Sorry, try again"

Tags: iterm2

Using my macbook pro running Monterey and using Iterm2 Build 3.4.16. I setup my account using the password manager, when I get prompted for a password Iterm2 detects this and brings up the password manager. I choose the account and it appears to paste in the password that I setup but it always returns the line "Sorry, try again". This output would be expected if you entered an incorrect password.

As a test I bring up the password manager when I'm not being prompted for a password, I get the warning asking if I want to still enter the Password, after confirming it does enter the correct password on my screen. I also verified this while using VI, the iterm2 password manager adds the correct password followed by a new line